# Superfluous (erroneous) message in the Windows message loop of child window when selecting a file

Tags: c, winapi

I create the main window and on it a child window and a file selection button. In the selection process, double clicking on a file results in a false message WM_MOUSEMOVE (with GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) < 0) in the message loop of the child window. This happens in the case when the click point is over the child window. In this case, the coordinates of the click point are transferred to the lParam. If you select the file via the open button, then there is nothing like it.

This message is not limited to the moment the file is selected: it enters the queue and fires after the selection. This can cause big problems, in particular when the child window is graphical.

Windows 8, VS 2015, C++.

Does anyone have any idea how to overcome this?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <shobjidl_core.h>      


#define IDI_ICON                        110
#define IDC_OPEN_FILE_BUTTON            120



HWND                                g_hDwnd = NULL;
HWND                                g_hWnd = NULL;
HWND                                hwndOpenFile = NULL;            


HRESULT InitWindow( HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow );
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc( HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM );
LRESULT CALLBACK    ChildProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);


int WINAPI wWinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow )
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( hPrevInstance );
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( lpCmdLine );

    if( FAILED( InitWindow( hInstance, nCmdShow ) ) )
        return 0;

    MSG msg = {0};

    while( WM_QUIT != msg.message )
    {
        if( PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ) )
        {
            TranslateMessage( &msg );
            DispatchMessage( &msg );
        }

    }

     return ( int )msg.wParam;
}




HRESULT InitWindow( HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow )
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcdex;
    wcdex.cbSize = sizeof( WNDCLASSEX );
    wcdex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcdex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcdex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcdex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcdex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcdex.hIcon = LoadIcon( hInstance, ( LPCTSTR )IDI_ICON );
    wcdex.hCursor = LoadCursor( NULL, IDC_ARROW );
    wcdex.hbrBackground = ( HBRUSH )( COLOR_WINDOW + 1 );
    wcdex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcdex.lpszClassName = L"ParentWindowClass";
    wcdex.hIconSm = LoadIcon( wcdex.hInstance, ( LPCTSTR )IDI_ICON );

    if( !RegisterClassEx( &wcdex ) )
        return E_FAIL;


    g_hDwnd = CreateWindow( L"ParentWindowClass", L"Test", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                           CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 840, 480, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL );
    if( !g_hDwnd )
        return E_FAIL;

    hwndOpenFile = CreateWindowEx(0, L"BUTTON", L"Open", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 
                        560, 50, 100, 24, g_hDwnd, (HMENU)IDC_OPEN_FILE_BUTTON, hInstance, NULL);

    ShowWindow( g_hDwnd, nCmdShow );
    UpdateWindow(g_hDwnd);              


    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_DBLCLKS;                  
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = ChildProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = NULL;
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(200, 200, 205));
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = L"ChildWindowClass";
    wcex.hIconSm = NULL;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
        return E_FAIL;

    g_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW, L"ChildWindowClass", L"test", WS_CHILD,
                                10, 10, 540, 460, g_hDwnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);          

    if (!g_hWnd)
        return E_FAIL;  

    ShowWindow(g_hWnd, nCmdShow);   
    UpdateWindow(g_hWnd);       

    return S_OK;
}



void OpenModelFile()
{
    char input;
    LPWSTR g_path = NULL;   

    LPWSTR szAPX = L"Model format";
    COMDLG_FILTERSPEC rgSpec[] = { { szAPX, L"*.txt" } };

    IFileDialog *pfd;
    if (SUCCEEDED(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pfd))))
    {
        DWORD dwOptions;

        if (SUCCEEDED(pfd->GetOptions(&dwOptions)))
        {
            pfd->SetOptions(dwOptions | FOS_STRICTFILETYPES);
        }

        if (SUCCEEDED(pfd->SetFileTypes(1, rgSpec)))
        {
            if (SUCCEEDED(pfd->SetDefaultExtension(L"txt")))
            {
                if (SUCCEEDED(pfd->SetFileName(L"Model.txt")))          
                {

                    if (SUCCEEDED(pfd->Show(NULL)))
                    {
                        IShellItem *psi;
                        if (SUCCEEDED(pfd->GetResult(&psi)))
                        {

                            if (SUCCEEDED(psi->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_NORMALDISPLAY, &g_path)))
                            {
                                LPCTSTR a = L"Path";    
                                MessageBox(NULL, g_path, a, NULL);
                            }
                            psi->Release();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        pfd->Release();
    }

    return;

}   





LRESULT CALLBACK ChildProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    int x ;
    int y ;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:

            hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        break;

    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:

        if (GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) < 0)    
        {

            x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam) ;
            y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam) ;
        }

        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:

        PostQuitMessage(0);

        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;

}   




LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    int id = LOWORD(wParam);

    switch( message )
    {
        case WM_PAINT:

            hdc = BeginPaint( hWnd, &ps );
            EndPaint( hWnd, &ps );

            break;

        case  WM_COMMAND:

            if (id == IDC_OPEN_FILE_BUTTON)                         
            {
                OpenModelFile();
            }

            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:

            PostQuitMessage( 0 );
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc( hWnd, message, wParam, lParam );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: @ Anders I just wanted to find it out.

Comment: [Why do I get spurious WM_MOUSEMOVE messages?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031001-00/?p=42343) Although I'm almost convinced, that the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message you get is genuine. Double-clicking is hard to do *without* moving the mouse.

Comment: @ IInspectable. 1. The recipe that Chen gives in his book: "So if your program wants to detect whether the mouse has moved, you need to add a check in your WM_MOUSEMOVE that the mouse position is different from the position reported by the previous WM_MOUSEMOVE message." is no good. In this case, before double clicking there are no messages WM_MOUSEMOVE, so, the comparison will still give a non-zero value.

Comment: @ IInspectable. 2. "Although I'm almost convinced, that the WM_MOUSEMOVE message you get is genuine." You want to say that the offset in the file selection window should give WM_MOUSEMOVE in the underlying window? This is a very strange behavior!

Comment: This is correct Windows behavior - the message stream from the system always goes first to the child window that has the focus - you the programmer choose whether you are interested in that message and respond appropriately - however order and number of messages is indeterminate - you cannot and should not code to expect messages to arrive in a particular sequence.

Comment: So, once your mouse is over the child window, it is automatically receiving the message stream, the first of which is likely to be a mouse move.  Depending on the type of mouse and the resolution settings, each increment of movement (a 'mickey' - I swear !) generates a new WM_MOUSEMOVE message.

Comment: @ Jeff D. The child window has no focus. The focus belongs to the file selection window.

Comment: @ Jeff D. The mouse does not move over the child window, and even more so with the left button pressed!

Comment: It looks like a real glitch of the operating system and I cannot yet figure out how to overcome it.

Comment: @ Jeff D. In particular, as I said, there are no problems when choosing a file through a button. And in this case there is no WM_MOUSEMOVE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem in a simple workaround. After double-clicking, I set the special flag to 1 and drop it to zero at the end of the WM_MOUSEMOVE message. In the message loop, I take into account the movement of the mouse only when the flag is lowered.

It turned out that in Windows 10 a whole series of false WM_MOUSEMOVE messages is generated. Thus, in addition to the flag mentioned above, which protects against the first message, it is necessary to take advantage of the advice of R. Chen from his book "Old New Things" and integrate the comparison of the current message with the previous one. If they match, then the message is not taken into account.

Adventure continues. The same spurious message appears when you double click on the window title. It is necessary also to raise the aforementioned flag when Windows sends WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem; the CLSID_FileOpenDialog modal dialog leaks mouse moves with MK_LBUTTON flag to any window underneath when the user double-clicks the selection (Microsoft bug). In my case the window underneath is a 3D viewport responding to these messages.

I found a better solution by having the viewport track left mouse button state via the WM_LBUTTONDOWN and WM_LBUTTONUP messages. Then ignore mouse moves with MK_LBUTTON flag when button state is not down. This is cleaner (no global flags, related code all in one place).